# Sharepoint 2013 - workflow to show/hide form fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, custom-list

I have a custom list and would like to know if anyone knows if there is a way to show and hide fields according to choice selection using a workflow?

Comment: why dont you use simple javascript and css?

Comment: The reason I have asked for another solution is my custom form refuses to acknowledge the JavaScript I usually insert - it will work in other custom forms - it has other styles and script in the page. Something is causing a conflict and I am out of time to trouble shoot so a new solution is needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are few possible ways:

1. Use JavaScript/CSS in the Content Editor Webpart to show/hide the
   fields
2. Use of Content Types.  A very useful article/tutorial [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hide-columns-sharepoint-list-using-multiple-content-types-maniyani)
3. Create a custom form through SharePoint Designer or PowerShell and hide the fields not required. Some information [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82725/hiding-a-column-from-users) and [here](http://promx.net/en/2016/09/how-to-hide-columns-from-sharepoint-forms/)

Comment: I know I am able to do this with script - wanted to know if it could be done with workflows

Comment: Did you check option 2

Comment: I have had a closer look at this option. The reason I have asked for another solution is my custom form refuses to acknowledge the JavaScript I usually insert. It may be a solution. Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: NO I haven't got back to it. I have been pulled away doing other work. I hope to get back to it soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you have content types enabled to show / hide fields the workflow can set the content type and therefore changing what the next user sees when they open the item.

Here is a related post with information about a workflow setting content types to change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489477/sharepoint-change-content-type-in-sharepoint-designer-using-workflow